# View prompt on all syncronized panes

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I'm currently configuring tmux to access to some servers.
I know how to split the view in panes and how to syncronize input between all the panes.

All is working great; it's just annoying that when i enable `synchronize-panes`, I can see the blinking prompt only on the active pane. This is especially true when editing the same file.

Is there a way to show the blinking prompt on all the synchronized panes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, terminals only offer one cursor, there is no way to have multiple cursors. tmux doesn't support drawing a fake cursor or anything like that. I can't think of any way you can achieve this at the moment.

Comment: I've tried to look at the code but... i'm not a c developer, i understood so little about it.
Maybe this could be a feature for one of the future release.
Thank you Nicholas for all the effort and the work you've done on tmux!